# Javascript to simulate typing in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div that I'd like to see the contents after a user types. This differs across different browsers for certain keys (like newlines and backspace).

For testing, I'd like to simulate this typing with javascript. Is there any way to do this?

I need more than just triggering events (which the majority of the questions on SO on javascript key triggering are about); I need the browser to see the 'enter' key was hit and do its thing to modify the contenteditable div. I'm interested in what the browser ultimately does so just listening for certain keystrokes and modifying the HTML myself would thus defeat the purpose.

Comment: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) has a [type](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#type) method, but I'm not sure exactly how realistic it is.

Answer (score 0):

This answer won't give you a way to do it via JavaScript, but I would recommend the browser automation testing tool, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this kind of testing. It will allow you to test the div as a user would interact with it.